# JQuery request - возвращать свои сообщения

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, request

Есть например JQuery ajax запрос к php файлу, в php файл возвращает "лог" так как скрипт долго выполняется.

Пользователь нажал кнопку, и типа пошли сообщения

```
--- сгенерирован файл
--- собрана таблица
--- скачивается файл
--- готово
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Веб-сервер отдаст результат только когда php скрипт закончит свое выполнение полностью. Вариантом является посылка ajax запросов по очереди и соответственно разделить обработку в php файле на части.

Comment: Эх, такая же идея была, думал есть более умное решение)